# Taylor series has zero convergence radius?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

Let $$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{n}(0)x^n}{n!}$$ where the $$|f^{n}(0)| \le C\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{\alpha})}{\alpha^{\frac{n+1}{\alpha}+1}}$$

for a constant $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$. Does this imply that the series has a positive radius of convergence? If I assume $\alpha \ge 1$ then the answer is obviously yes, but for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ I am not sure anymore.

For $\alpha=1$ for example, we have $|f^{n}(0)| \le C\ n!$ so that the radius of convergence is $1$.

The main issue here seems to be whether we can bound $\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{\alpha})}{n!}$ by something that grows not faster than exponentially in $n$ ?

Comment: The statement "the radius of convergence is $1$" is inaccurate. The convergence radius (of the Taylor series) is *atleast* $1$ is the correct statement. It's also worth pointing out that if you find (as the answer below shows) that the dominating series $\sum C\frac{\Gamma(\cdot)}{\alpha^\cdots} x^n$ diverges for all $x$ then it does **not** follow that the Taylor series has zero convergence radius. We can't say anything about the convergence properties in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$\Gamma(n)
\sim cn^{-1/2}(n/e)^n
$,

$\begin{array}\\
t_n
&=\dfrac{\Gamma((n+1)/a)}{n!a^{(n+1)/a+1}}\\
&\sim \dfrac{c((n+1)/a)^{-1/2}((n+1)/(ae))^{(n+1)/a}}{cn^{1/2}(n/e)^na^{(n+1)/a+1}}\\
&\sim \dfrac{(1/a)^{-1/2}e^{n-((n+1)/a)}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{n(n)^na^{2(n+1)/a+1}}\\
&\sim \dfrac{(1/a)^{-1/2}e^{n(1-1/a)-1/a}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{n^{n+1}a^{2(n+1)/a+1}}\\
&\sim \dfrac{e^{n(1-1/a)}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{a(1/a)^{1/2}e^{1/a}n^{n+1}a^{2(n+1)/a}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a^{1/2}e^{1/a}} \dfrac{e^{n(1-1/a)}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{n^{n+1}a^{2(n+1)/a}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a^{1/2}e^{1/a}} \dfrac{e^{(n+1)(1-1/a)-1+1/a}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{n^{n+1}a^{2(n+1)/a}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a^{1/2}e} \dfrac{e^{(n+1)(1-1/a)}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{n^{n+1}a^{2(n+1)/a}}\\
&=c \dfrac{e^{(n+1)(1-1/a)}((n+1))^{(n+1)/a}}{n^{n+1}a^{2(n+1)/a}}\\
\text{so}\\
t_n^{1/(n+1)}
&\sim c^{1/(n+1)} \dfrac{e^{(1-1/a)}((n+1))^{1/a}}{na^{2/a}}\\
&\sim  \dfrac{e^{(1-1/a)}((n+1)/n)^{1/a}}{n^{1-1/a}a^{2/a}}\\
&\sim  \dfrac{e^{(1-1/a)}}{n^{1-1/a}a^{2/a}}\\
\end{array}
$

If $a=1$,
this gives
$t_n^{1/(n+1)}
\sim 1
$,
which agrees with OP's statement.

If $a > 1$,
then
$1-1/a
> 0
$,
so
$t_n^{1/(n+1)}
\to 0
$,
so the root test
says the series converges for
all $x$.

If
$0 < a < 1$,
then
$1-1/a
\lt 0
$,
so that
$t_n^{1/(n+1)}
\to \infty
$,
so the root test
says the series diverges for
all $x$.